# Logic If Else not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am back again struggling with one of my VBA codes! I created the following code to perform a validation - If no value found in cell A1, then find another open Excel WB, copy date and further resume with the process. This is working, however if values found simply start the process. I feel I haven't placed an "Else" at the right place, any suggestions, would be a big help!
The ELSE that I'm talking about is under "FIND ME".

```
Sub Cvent003_Uploads()
    Sheets("Add File Here").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
        Worksheets("Master Mapper").Activate

        Dim answer003 As Integer
        answer003 = MsgBox("Please check the Data Sheet. No value found in first row! Do you wish to find Cvent003 file in open workbooks and start process?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
        If answer003 = vbYes Then
            'Starts here
            Dim wSheet As Worksheet
            Dim wBook As Workbook
            Dim rFound As Range
            Dim bFound As Boolean
            Dim lngLastRow2 As Long

            On Error Resume Next
            For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
                For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets
                    Set rFound = Nothing
                    Set rFound = wSheet.Range("D1:D2").Find(What:="Meeting Manager", SearchFormat:=True, After:=wSheet.Range("D1"), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)

                    'rFound.Cells.Select
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        bFound = True
                        Application.Goto rFound, True
                        'Rows(1, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        lngLastRow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                        Range("A1:G" & lngLastRow2).Copy
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add File Here").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next wSheet
                If bFound = True Then Exit For
            Next wBook

            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No open file for Cvent003 Meetings Found. Make sure the most recent Cvent003 Excel WB is open!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'FIND ME

        Else

            Sheets("Add File Here").Select
            Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
            Range("A1").Value = "Meeting Name"

            Dim lngLastRow As Long
            lngLastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=C2:C" & lngLastRow & "&"" - ""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)
            Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete

            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=";", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=":", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=",", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="(", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=")", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="{", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="}", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="[", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="]", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="~+", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="~*", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="~?", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="_", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=".", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="'", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="\", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="/", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=".", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:="@", Replacement:=""
            Columns("A").Replace _
             What:=Chr(34), Replacement:=""

            Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("C1").Value = "Client ID"
            Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("E1").Value = "Planner Name"
            Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("J1").Value = "External System Name"

            Dim rngID As Range
            Dim PID As Long
            Dim ClientID As Long
            ClientID = Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Copy
            'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
            Set rngID = Range("B2:B500")
            For Each cell In rngID
                'test if cell is empty
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    'write to adjacent cell
                    'Range("G2:G" & lngLastRow).Value.Copy
                    Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow).Value = Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Value
                    'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = EndDate.PasteSpecial

                End If
            Next

            Dim cellID As Range
            For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow)
                'If Len(cell.Value) > 3 Then cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
                cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
            Next cell

            Columns(6).EntireColumn.Delete

            Dim rngP As Range
            Dim Pi As Long

            'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
            Set rngP = Range("D2:D500")
            For Each cell In rngP
                'test if cell is empty
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    'write to adjacent cell
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"
                End If
            Next
            Dim rngE As Range
            Dim Ei As Long

            'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
            Set rngE = Range("H2:H500")
            For Each cell In rngE
                'test if cell is empty
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    'write to adjacent cell
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Cvent"
                End If
            Next

            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

            Dim answer As Integer
            answer = MsgBox("Temporary File Prepared for Cvent003. Do you wish to proceed with MMS_NewMtgs file creation?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                Call Prepare_OutputFile
            Else
                MsgBox "Output file not created!! Please select - Click to create MMS Formatted File from Master Mapper.", vbOKOnly
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'MsgBox "File has been formatted for Cvent002 and is ready for MMS upload. Please copy values and paste to Standard Format File on your system!", vbOKOnly
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the `ELSE` attached to? The `If answer003 = vbYes Then` line?  Also, if you step through your code with `F8`, where does it skip `ELSE` when you expect it to occur?

Comment: Do yourself a favour - learn how to consistently indent your code.  It will make finding these issues so much easier.

Comment: I'm still pretty new with VBA, just an arrangement to make my daily reporting easy.
@BruceWayne - Look for the Else that is after "FIND ME"
Else is supposed to be attached to 
     If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then

Comment: As @BruceWayne said, the `Else` after `FIND ME` is attached to the `If answer003 = vbYes Then` statement.  I have edited the question to indent your code so that it is more readable.  Where did you want the `Else` to be?

Comment: @YowE3K I really appreciate you helping me with this. I ideally want the Else to be attached to 
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then

Comment: Then place an `Else` just before where you currently have that `If` statement's `End If`, and then include between that new `Else` and the `End If` the code which you wish to perform if the `If` evaluates to `False`.  (With the indented code, just move your cursor down in the same column as the "I" of the `If` until you reach an "E" of an `End If` - that will be the `End If` associated with the `If`.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what code you want to execute when, but if it is just a case of you having placed code as the `Else` block of `If answer003 = vbYes Then` instead of `If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then` then just move that code after the `End If` of `If answer003 = vbYes Then`:

```
Sub Cvent003_Uploads()
    Sheets("Add File Here").Select
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
        Worksheets("Master Mapper").Activate

        Dim answer003 As Integer
        answer003 = MsgBox("Please check the Data Sheet. No value found in first row! Do you wish to find Cvent003 file in open workbooks and start process?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
        If answer003 = vbYes Then
            'Starts here
            Dim wSheet As Worksheet
            Dim wBook As Workbook
            Dim rFound As Range
            Dim bFound As Boolean
            Dim lngLastRow2 As Long

            On Error Resume Next
            For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
                For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets
                    Set rFound = Nothing
                    Set rFound = wSheet.Range("D1:D2").Find(What:="Meeting Manager", SearchFormat:=True, After:=wSheet.Range("D1"), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)

                    'rFound.Cells.Select
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        bFound = True
                        Application.Goto rFound, True
                        'Rows(1, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        lngLastRow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                        Range("A1:G" & lngLastRow2).Copy
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add File Here").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next wSheet
                If bFound = True Then Exit For
            Next wBook

            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No open file for Cvent003 Meetings Found. Make sure the most recent Cvent003 Excel WB is open!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'FIND ME

        End If

    Else

        Sheets("Add File Here").Select
        Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
        Range("A1").Value = "Meeting Name"

        Dim lngLastRow As Long
        lngLastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=C2:C" & lngLastRow & "&"" - ""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)
        Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete

        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=";", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=":", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=",", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="(", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=")", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="{", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="}", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="[", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="]", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="~+", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="~*", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="~?", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="_", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=".", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="'", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="\", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="/", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=".", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:="@", Replacement:=""
        Columns("A").Replace _
         What:=Chr(34), Replacement:=""

        Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("C1").Value = "Client ID"
        Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("E1").Value = "Planner Name"
        Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("J1").Value = "External System Name"

        Dim rngID As Range
        Dim PID As Long
        Dim ClientID As Long
        ClientID = Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Copy
        'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
        Set rngID = Range("B2:B500")
        For Each cell In rngID
            'test if cell is empty
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                'write to adjacent cell
                'Range("G2:G" & lngLastRow).Value.Copy
                Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow).Value = Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Value
                'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = EndDate.PasteSpecial

            End If
        Next

        Dim cellID As Range
        For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow)
            'If Len(cell.Value) > 3 Then cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
        Next cell

        Columns(6).EntireColumn.Delete

        Dim rngP As Range
        Dim Pi As Long

        'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
        Set rngP = Range("D2:D500")
        For Each cell In rngP
            'test if cell is empty
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                'write to adjacent cell
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"
            End If
        Next
        Dim rngE As Range
        Dim Ei As Long

        'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
        Set rngE = Range("H2:H500")
        For Each cell In rngE
            'test if cell is empty
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                'write to adjacent cell
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Cvent"
            End If
        Next

        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        Dim answer As Integer
        answer = MsgBox("Temporary File Prepared for Cvent003. Do you wish to proceed with MMS_NewMtgs file creation?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            Call Prepare_OutputFile
        Else
            MsgBox "Output file not created!! Please select - Click to create MMS Formatted File from Master Mapper.", vbOKOnly
        End If
    End If
    'MsgBox "File has been formatted for Cvent002 and is ready for MMS upload. Please copy values and paste to Standard Format File on your system!", vbOKOnly
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Note: I have no idea whether that code now makes logical sense - I just rearranged the blocks without trying to understand what you are doing.  I'm especially not sure what the implications are of doing nothing if the user answers "No" to your `"Please check the Data Sheet. No value found in first row! Do you wish to find Cvent003 file in open workbooks and start process?"` question. I.e. If they answer "No", your code is flagging the workbook as having been saved - is that really appropriate?

Comment: I am so sorry to be a pain, but with this code, now it executes if cell A1 is not blank, but if it is blank, it copies the data to my desired sheet and just stops!
To answer your previous comment, if No is selected, I'm fine with it just exiting the sub and stopping there!

Comment: @AkshaySachdev - Do you expect `A1` to be truly empty, or perhaps have a formula that is evaluating to `""`?  Also, you can step through code with `F8` to watch it line by line - I sugges doing that and seeing why the code just stops, as there's probably a condition that's (not) being met.

Comment: So you don't want this code to be executed as part of the `Else`, you want it executed always?  If so, move it after the `End If`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried step by step with    `F8   , if cell    `A1    is not empty it jumps to the End. My idea behind this is, if cell `A1    is Empty, find an open WB and copy data. Then, execute the remaining part of the code to create a file in my desired format. If cell  `A1    is not empty, do not copy any data, just process the code starting from  `Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove

Comment: @AkshaySachdev If you needed a `GoTo` then you probably didn't code it right.  (`GoTo` statements are rarely needed in VBA these days, and certainly not for what I believe you were trying to achieve.)

Comment: @YowE3K, I second you, but had no other option. I had really invested a lot of time in finding a fix for my issues.